# Overwriting require path with file extension in intern js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, intern

I am requiring a class in the 3rd party and that class has `require(somePath\someClass.js)` inside of it.
When the above require path has  .js extension, the mapping that I defined in intern.js does not apply `somePath: myProject\lib\somePath`and got a require error.

when I changed the above path to `require(somePath\someClass)` in the 3rd party lib by removing the .js extension, the mapping applies fine.

Is there any configure that I can overwrite the require path in intern to make intern happy?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't technically an issue with Intern itself, but is a [defined behavior of the Dojo AMD loader](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/loader/amd.html#id7) used by Intern 3.x. `somePath/someClass` is treated as a *module identifier*, while `somePath/someClass.js` is treated as a *generic script*. The loading semantics for these are different; for example, the module value won't be returned when requiring `somePath/someClass.js`.

All of that said, you could try defining a mapping from the generic script path (`somePath/someClass.js`) to the corresponding module identifier (`somePath/someClass`).